# C# WPF App Load New Data into Data Grid without Erasing Previous Data

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I'm writing a little program that will read a header file off of a Floppy disk, then output the contents of the header file to a data grid table.  I would like this data grid table to add a new row to the data grid every time a new floppy is loaded.

Currently, my code will read the floppy and output the desired data to the data grid.  However, each time I put in a new floppy and press the Load button, it will simply overwrite the data already in the table with the data from the new floppy.  I want it to keep the data in the table, and add a new row to show the data from the new floppy.

I suspect that I am creating a new table every time I push the "Load" button, and then just filling the table with the current data.  I just don't know how to not do that...

Here is what I am doing:

This is the .xaml portion where i created the data grid:

```
<DataGrid Name="TableData" AutogenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header = "Seq #" Binding="{Binding SeqNum}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header = "Disk Num" Binding="{Binding HdrDisk}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header = "Date/Time" Binding="{Binding HdrDTG}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header = "File Size" Binding="{Binding fileSize}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header = "# of Disks" Binding="{Binding TotalDisk}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Clumns>
```

This is where i create the class to bind the data:

```
public class TableDataClass
{
        public int HdrDisk {get;set;}
        public string HdrDTG {get;set;}
        public int TotalDisk {get;set;}
        public int SeqNum {get;set;}
        public in fileSize {get;set;}
}
```

And this is where I do the load from the Floppy, process the data, and output to the data grid.

```
private void loadFromFloppy(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

// A bunch of stuff that I do to process reading in the floppy
// ..
// ..
// ..

// disknum, asciistring, totDiskNum, seqNumCount, fileSizeTemp are all properly
// calculated and filled in this part.
// ..
// ..

//Output Data to Data Grid Table
List<TableDataClass> tableData = new List<TableDataClass>();

tableData.Add(new TableDataClass()
{
        HdrDisk =disknum,
        HDRDTG = asciiString,
        TotalDisk = totDiskNum,
        SeqNum = seqNumCount,
        fileSize = fileSizeTemp
});

TableData.ItemsSource = tableData;

}
```

Comment: use `ObservableCollection` in place of List and Add new object to the collection each time. set the `ItemSource` in `XAML` use `Properties` to bind the `ItemSource`

Comment: Do you mean to replace my TableDataClass with an ObservableCollection class? Edit - ah you clarified your comment a bit.  Replace list with ObservableCollection.. Ok I can give that a shot.

Comment: Ok yea.  I had to do  a fair bit of editing my code to change everything, but I have switched to an ObservableCollection and it is now working as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to a problem I was having a few weeks back. My suggestion would be to simply add another row to a data table, for example:

```
DataTable dt = myDataGridView.DataSource;
DataRow row = dt.NewRow(); //This sets "row" to a new, completely blank row with all the columns in "dt"
row["HdrDisk"] = disknum
(And all the other fields...)
dt.Rows.Add(row);
myDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

This should work(in theory).

Comment: I appreciate the input.  I don't think this is quite the type of solution I was looking for. I've been exploring the ObservableCollection that Abin mentioned and it appears to be what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this answer comes from the suggestion of Abin.  I wanted to provide it for any others struggling with this.

I switched from a List to an ObservableCollection.

I added the following code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

        private ObservableCollection<TableDataClass> tableDataFill; //This line is new


        public MainWindow()
        {
            Initialize Component();
            tableDataFill = new ObservableCollection<TableDataClass>() {}; //This line is new
        }
```

Then, down where I was trying to fill the table with the list, I changed it from the above to the following:

```
tableDataFill.add(new TableDataClass ()
{
    HdrDisk =disknum,
    HDRDTG = asciiString,
    TotalDisk = totDiskNum,
    SeqNum = seqNumCount,
    fileSize = fileSizeTemp
}

TableData.ItemsSource = tableDataFill;
```

It took a fair bit of restructuring my code and moving away from List, but it is working now.

Thanks again to Abin.